# Uninstall Multiple Applications in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function that goes through the array $packages to uninstall multiple built in applications that come with new PCs. When running this script I am receiving an error "null-valued expression" At line 6 char 3 $app.Uninstall(). Any see where i went wrong?

```
foreach($package in $packages){
  $app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match "$package"
  }
  $app.Uninstall()
}
```

Comment: You may read this before you proceed ... [Please Stop Using Win32_Product To Find Installed Software. Alternatives Inside!](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/)

Comment: @Olaf thank you! Ill give this a read, friends don't let friends query Win32_Product :)

Comment: @Olaf does this mean i need to use Get-ItemProperty in place of Win32_Product?

Comment: ?? ... what? ... how? No. How did you populate your variable `$packages`?

Comment: Sorry as u can see i dont do powershell much... attempting it on my free time :-) $packages = @("solitairecollection", "zunemusic")

Comment: If u recommend any resources on how to get big brain on Powershell, i will gladly indulge the info

Comment: I'd recommend to start with learning the very basics of PowerShell first ... [PowerShell 101](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/00-introduction?view=powershell-7.3). To search for cmdlets designed to deal with packages you can use PowerShell `Get-Command -Noun *package*`. Please always read the help for the cmdlets you're about to use completely including the examples to learn how to use them.

Comment: Regardless of that ... in the vast majority of the cases you're not the very first one with a given task. Use your prefered internet search engine to search for examples you can adapt to your particular needs.

Comment: `uninstall-package app1,app2,app3`

Comment: appxpackages would be a different story, `remove-appxpackage packagename`

Comment: @Olaf thank you i appreciate it and being so quick with responses.

Comment: @js2010 same to you!